# PHP output data

Tags: php

When Im trying to validate my PHP output data my echo string puts a `<br />` after the tag, how can I prevent this ?

as you see in the first row after  background-color: an 
 shows up from no where and it's screwing up my validatation.

Im trying to validate in Transitional

This is my entire script

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en"><head> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /> 
<title>Visitkort</title> 

<style type="text/css">
body {
    background-color:#efefef;
}

#kort{
position:absolute;
margin-top:30px;
padding-left:5px;
padding-right:25px;
margin-left:450px;
background-color:<?php echo($_POST['color']);?>;
color:<?php echo($_REQUEST['fontcolor']);?>;
font-family: <?php echo($_REQUEST['typsnitt']);?>;
}
</style>

</head>

<body>


<form id="form" method="post" action="visitkort.php">
<table width="300">
<tr>
<td>Företag: </td>
<td>    
<input type="text" name="enterprise" id="enterprise" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['enterprise']) ? $_POST['enterprise'] : '' ?>" />
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
Efternamn: </td>
<td>
<input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['lastname']) ? $_POST['lastname'] : '' ?>"/>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>namn: </td>
<td>
<input type="text" name="namn" id="namn" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['namn']) ? $_POST['namn'] : '' ?>"/>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
Title:</td>
<td> 
<input type="text" name="title" id="title" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['title']) ? $_POST['title'] : '' ?>"/>
</td>
</tr><tr>
<td>
Phone:
</td>
<td> 
<input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['phone']) ? $_POST['phone'] : '' ?>"/>
</td>
</tr><tr>
<td>
E-mail:
</td>
<td>
<input type="text" name="mail" id="mail" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['mail']) ? $_POST['mail'] : '' ?>"/>
</td>
</tr><tr>
<td>
Typsnitt:
</td>
<td>
<select id="typsnitt" name="typsnitt">
<option value="Verdana">Verdana</option>
<option value="Arial">Arial</option>
<option value="Tahoma">Tahoma</option>
<option value="Impact">Impact</option>
</select>
</td>
</tr><tr>
<td>
Bakgrundsfärg: 
</td>
<td>
<select name="color" id="color">
<option value="#799ef1" 
<?php if(isset($_POST['color']) && $_POST['color'] == '#799ef1') 
echo ' selected="selected"';
?>
>Ljus blå</option>

<option value="#f0f179" 
<?php if(isset($_POST['color']) && $_POST['color'] == '#f0f179') 
echo ' selected="selected"';
?>
>Ljus gult</option>
<option value="#fff" 
<?php if(isset($_POST['color']) && $_POST['color'] == '#fff') 
echo ' selected="selected"';
?>
>Vit</option>

<option value="#64b6c1" 
<?php if(isset($_POST['color']) && $_POST['color'] == '#64b6c1') 
echo ' selected="selected"';
?>
>Turkos</option>
<option value="red" 
<?php if(isset($_POST['color']) && $_POST['color'] == 'red') 
echo ' selected="selected"';
?>
>röd</option>
</select>
</td>
</tr><tr>

<td>
Textfärg: 
</td>
<td>
<select name="fontcolor" id="fontcolor">
<option value="#000" 
<?php if(isset($_POST['fontcolor']) && $_POST['fontcolor'] == '#799ef1') 
echo ' selected="selected"';
?>
>Välj Färg</option>

<option value="#799ef1" 
<?php if(isset($_POST['fontcolor']) && $_POST['fontcolor'] == '#799ef1') 
echo ' selected="selected"';
?>
>Ljus blå</option>

<option value="#f0f179" 
<?php if(isset($_POST['fontcolor']) && $_POST['fontcolor'] == '#f0f179') 
echo ' selected="selected"';
?>
>Ljus gult</option>
<option value="#fff" 
<?php if(isset($_POST['fontcolor']) && $_POST['fontcolor'] == '#fff') 
echo ' selected="selected"';
?>
>Vit</option>

<option value="#64b6c1" 
<?php if(isset($_POST['fontcolor']) && $_POST['fontcolor'] == '#64b6c1') 
echo ' selected="selected"';
?>
>Turkos</option>
<option value="red" 
<?php if(isset($_POST['fontcolor']) && $_POST['fontcolor'] == 'red') 
echo ' selected="selected"';
?>
>röd</option>
</select>
</td>
</tr><tr>

<td colspan="2">
<input type="submit" name="go" id="go" value="Skapa visitkort" />
<input type="button" value="Rensa" onclick="window.location.reload();return false" />
</td>
</tr>

</form>

<div id="kort">
<?php

if(isset($_REQUEST["go"])){ 
echo($_REQUEST["enterprise"] . "<br/>");    
echo($_REQUEST["lastname"] . " "); 
echo($_REQUEST["namn"] . "<br/>");
echo($_REQUEST["title"] . "<br/>"."<br/>");     
echo($_REQUEST["phone"] . "<br/>"); 
echo($_REQUEST["mail"] . "<br/>");  

}
else{ 
?>

<?php

}
?>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This output is from [xdebug](http://xdebug.org/), because there is an error. `$_POST['color']` is not defined.

> Notice: Undefined index: color in C:\wamp\www\Labb3.1\visitkort.php on line 10

You should **always** validate user input before using it for anything. Verify it's a value that you can use, and is safe to use, before printing to the output. If it's an array like `$_POST`, make sure the index exists before attempting to read it.

Be very careful to validate and filter any user input you use in your output, and be mindful of [XSS attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting). This is not merely a suggestion, but something you should be dedicated to.

Learn more: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_%28XSS%29

To simply prevent the error you have to do something like this:

```
background-color:<?php echo isset($_POST['color']) ? $_POST['color'] : 'someDefaultColor'; ?>;
```

#### However:

You really should validate the values, at the very least `htmlspecialchars($_POST['color'])`, but even then - you can get broken CSS which will affect the entire page. Consider writing one or more validation/filtering functions to ensure the value is appropriate to use in CSS output (which is beyond the scope of this question). Make sure it's a 3 or 6 digit hex, or within a predetermined array of named color values.

Comment: Al the functions in the script is working fine, its just the validation thats complaining about the <br />.

Comment: Because the validator is not `$_POST`ing anything of course. The `<br />` is part of an error message. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/jk6JS/ Seriously, you have to validate user input, always, all the time. Make sure it exists, and make sure it's safe to use - every time. In the case of reading an array index that might not exist, make sure it does first or you will get the 'undefined index' notice. Then, once you've tested everything and it works, turn off error reporting so others can't exploit it.

Answer (score 0):

Where is the `$_POST['color']` getting it's content from? Very likely the problem can be found over there. Could you post the code which gives `$_POST['color']` it's value?

The echo statement isn't directly responsible for the `<br>` in this case.

Comment: This is the content post its getting it from.
<?php if(isset($_POST['color']) && $_POST['color'] == '#799ef1') 
echo ' selected="selected"';
?>

I started with PHP yesterday so im really newbe

Comment: Whele that's not where it get's it's value. isset checks if the value is set. In your code, when $_POST['color'] has an value, the script echoes 'selected'. The $_POST value is set earlier. Could you post the complete script in your start post or something?

Comment: I posted  the completed scripts :)

Comment: Alright, I see. Seems like the previous answer is perfectly correct. You're not validating; so an error message comes up which contains an <br>. By the way, after if(islet($_REQUEST['go']) your echoing values, followed by an <br>. When go isset, that isn't a guarantee that the other stuff your echoing has an value too. So the echo is empty, but completed with an <br>